# What is the correct setting for 'matches' array in a chrome extension for site filtering

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extendsion for chrome that I want to only run on certin sites so I set up the content_scripts key in manifest.json as follows

```json
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.amazon.*/*", "https://*.ebay.*/*","https://*.bestbuy.*/*/"],
      "js": ["src/ethical_extension.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
```

However the store submission was rejected with:

> Violation reference ID: Yellow Magnesium
> Violation: Not providing promised functionality
> "giving Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]'"

But setting the matches key to `"<all_urls>"` the submission is ok and is published just fine!

So my question is the either a required key that needs to be in the matches array for the automated test to pass? Otherwise does the specific site filtering need to be in the content script file directly?

Comment: what is the *promised functionality*?

Comment: it could be that `"https://*.amazon.*/*"` isn't a valid match ... I believe `*` in host part can only be at the start

Comment: From [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/match-patterns)... _"If you use a wildcard in the host pattern, it must be the first or only character, and it must be followed by a period (`.`) or forward slash (`/`)."_

Comment: Hi I was following this example from the docs
```https://*.google.com/foo*bar```
 Matches any URL using the https scheme, on a google.com host, with a path that starts with foo and ends with bar. Examples of matches include https://www.google.com/foo/baz/bar and https://docs.google.com/foobar.

Comment: So this seems whats needed:```["https://*.amazon.*/*", "https://*.ebay.*/*","https://*.bestbuy.*/*"]```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is you have to define the full domain so like this

```
"matches": [
        "https://*.amazon.ca/*",
        "https://*.amazon.de/*",
        "https://*.amazon.it/*",
        "https://*.amazon.fr/*",
        "https://*.amazon.nl/*",
        "https://*.amazon.es/*",
        "https://*.amazon.com/*",
        "https://*.ebay.ca/*",
        "https://*.bestbuy.ca/*"
      ]
```

I hope it helps someone